# PHP and MySQL average

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this structure in table named grades

```
1st row:        2nd row:
------------------------------
| english      |     math    |
------------------------------
| 3            |  4          |
| 4            |  4          |
| 5            |  2          |
| 2            |  5          |
------------------------------
```

How do I now calucate average of english row?

I tried with:

```
"SELECT AVG(english) as `averageenglish` FROM grades"
```

It always gives me "No database selected"

Comment: you need to select the database first. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html

Comment: Or else qualify the table reference with the database name.

Comment: I already selected database before in the code..

Comment: Well post it. It's hard to diagnose this without seeing the code doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database selections are per session.  If you go into the MySQL command prompt and type

```
USE MyDatabase
```

you do not have to qualify table names in queries for that session.  As soon as you leave (`exit`, <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, etc.) you don't have that privilege.  You will have to `USE` the database again or qualify table names in queries.  This includes a session created by a separate script that is not running on the command line.

In production code, it is helpful to always qualify table names in queries.  Your query should look like:

```
SELECT AVG(english) as averageenglish FROM MyDatabase.grades
```

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrated what @eggyal means

```
SELECT AVG(english) as `averageenglish` FROM databasename.grades
```

The preferred method is to add the database name to your connection if you only have one database.